# How to avoid argument name collision in R snow/ snowfall package, sfSapply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, r-raster

I'm trying to use the `snow` and `snowfall` packages, specifically the `sfSapply()` function to extract data from multiple raster files. It looks something like this:

```
queue <- list(rast1, rast2, rast3)
sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus=3)
sfLibrary(raster)
sfLibrary(rgdal)
sfLibrary(sp)
a <- sfSapply(queue, extract, sp=TRUE, fun=mean, y=tracts)
sfStop()
```

The `fun` argument passed to `sfSapply()` is intended for the `extract()` function (in the `raster` library). However, `sfSapply()` also takes a `fun` argument (`extract()`); in this example, I've provided it as the second positional argument.

How can I specify a `fun` argument for the passed function and not have it confused with the `fun` argument expected by `sfSapply()`?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to create a custom extract function that has these arguments built in:

```
sfRasterExtract=function(raster_obj){
extract(raster_obj, sp=TRUE, fun=mean, y=tracts)
}
```

Make sure to use sfExportAll() after sfInit to import the function to all instances you will use, then run

```
a <- sfSapply(queue, sfRasterExtract)
```